# Proving that given ideal is principal

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Given the ring
$$
R = \{a+b\sqrt2\ |\ a,b \in \Bbb Z\}
$$
with the standard addition and multiplication of real numbers and **$I$ is the principal ideal in it**, generated by $3+\sqrt2$. Prove that
$$
I = \{a+b\sqrt2\mid a-3b \equiv 0\pmod 7\}
$$
The following was my approach: The set (called principal ideal), generated by $3+\sqrt2$,
is $I = \{(3+\sqrt2)(a+b\sqrt2)\mid a,b \in \Bbb Z\}$. So we have to show that in

$(3+\sqrt2)(a+b\sqrt2) = 3a + 3b\sqrt2 + a\sqrt2 + 2b = (3a + 2b) + \sqrt2(3b + a),\ a -3b \equiv 0\pmod 7$.

If $3a + 2b = \alpha$ and $3b+a = \beta$ then $\alpha - \beta = 2a - b$.

And I'm stuck here. I don't have any clue how from this result I should get the wanted equality $a-3b \equiv 0\pmod 7$.

Comment: What is a *main* ideal??

Comment: In case "main ideal" is a literal translation of e.g. German "Hauptideal" - these are called *principal* ideals in English

Comment: Thank you, corrected it.

Comment: There is no such thing as **the**  principal ideal in a ring, in general.

Comment: I think your confusion might be that you are over-using $a,b$. Where you have said that you want to show that $a-3b\equiv 0 ( \mathrm{mod\ }7)$, you actually want to show that $\alpha-3 \beta\equiv 0 ( \mathrm{mod\ }7)$ with $\alpha,\beta$ as you have defined below. Then also remember that you need to show the other implication!

Comment: @GeorgeR I understood my mistake in "over-using $a,b$". Thank you!!